# How to call delete method on web API from sweet-alert in MVC-5?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sweetalert

I want to call the delete method in web API from my MVC-5 application using Ajax request within sweet-alert. Upon clicking the delete button, when user will confirm to delete that specific record on sweet-alert, the API delete method must call. However, the code does not call the method. I have the following code on my front-end:

```
$('#dtusers tbody').on('click', '#btnDeleteRecord', function () {
                var userId = $(this).attr("data-userid").valueOf();
                var details = userTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();     
                swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Delete " + details[0] + " " + details[1] + "?",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                    closeOnConfirm: true
                },
                function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: serviceUrl + "/api/account/deletedata",
                            method: 'DELETE',
                            data: { userId: userId },
                            success: function () {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
```

The web API delete method that I want to call is here:

```
[HttpDelete]
    [Route("deletedata")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteData(string userId)
    {
        if(userId == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("No data deleted");
        }

        DBAccess dblayer = new DBAccess();
        dblayer.DeleteData(userId);

        return Ok();
    }
```

I am not getting any errors in debugging the front end code and still, it is not calling the back-end method. Is there any issue within my code beyond my knowledge which is preventing the call. Or let me know about a perfect way to call my web API delete method by passing UserId to delete the specified record from the database.

Is there any appropriate solution to this? Or how I may improve the web API delete method to be called from Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some error when you try to access the Delete API call, did you try running Fiddler or Postman? 
If you get any **Error 405 – Methods not Allowed**, then it must be an issue with **WebDAVModule**, which  set PUT and DELETE request methods disabled by default. In order to make it work, you need to change these defaults or disable it for the whole web application.

In your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

If you still face issue, I suggest you to change HttpVerb to POST to handle delete data.

```
function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: serviceUrl + "/api/account/deletedata",
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: { userId: userId },
                            success: function () {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

[HttpPost]
    [Route("deletedata")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteData(string userId)
    {
        if(userId == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("No data deleted");
        }

        DBAccess dblayer = new DBAccess();
        dblayer.DeleteData(userId);

        return Ok();
    }
```